# pedestrian detection custom svm

Tags: image-processing, svm, detection

i am using this link as a guide but for human detection.
http://pythonopencv.com/best-and-easy-support-vector-machinessvm-hog-tutorial-opencv-3-0-3-1-3-2-3-3-windows-10-visual-studio-2015-x64-train-test/#comment-2087

i have inriaPerson dataset on witch i want to train my Svm and after use hog. 
My question is if my folder with positive images i need to have pedestrians with background or i have to crop them from picture. and here is wrote the images dimenssion has to be 64, 64 for cars detection, in mz case should be the same

Comment: Is my first time working with all this, and i couldn't find an exact tutorial on witch are the steps, and how it has to be done.

Comment: my first attempt was to use haar for training and then cascade but the results were so bad i had to change. I couldnt find the exact algorithm who gets the best results in pedestrian detection and an tutorial on how it has to be done

Comment: use the 64x128 pixels window for training. Also read the HOG paper for better understanding https://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/triggs/pubs/Dalal-cvpr05.pdf

Comment: i want to use my own dataset for training and here isnt wrote about that. but do you know if i have to crop the images or no?

Comment: first you have to choose window size e.g. 64x128 window was used by the Dalal, then you have to crop the images to 64x128 (or the size you have chosen) for training.